# Populating User Information List

Tags: user-profile, user-information-list

I am using the user information list as a contact list for our employees, and it works very well, it automatically pulls the Office, work phone, and mobile phone numbers, however I cannot get it to pull any other information.

I would like to have it pull the home phone or a custom field I have created for direct dial numbers.

I add the column in on the view, however the fields are all empty despite the fields being filled in on the SharePoint administration user pages.

Does anyone have any idea how to get this to populate if possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have SharePoint Server, implementing the User Profile Service will take care of this for you.

If you're using SharePoint Foundation, there is no out of the box method to update these other properties automatically. You would need to implement a pull from Active Directory to the UIL property for each user in the Site Collection. An example of that can be found [here](https://github.com/Nauplius/FoundationSync/blob/2013/UpdateUser.cs).

For SharePoint Online, you will need to implement a custom solution. Microsoft released a PnP sample named [Core.UserProfiles.Sync](https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP/tree/master/Samples/Core.UserProfiles.Sync) which you can follow to build your own solution.

Comment: I should have mentioned this is in an O365 enviroment with SharePoint online.

Comment: @TravisEaston see the updated answer to address SPO.